# Does Pyinstaller also bundles Python3?

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.10, pygui

I am trying to create a package of my Python3 script using Pyinstaller. I have one query: will the bundled file in the dist folder include python3 as well?

Will that executable work on a system that does not have python3 installed?

I am using the following command to create a single executable file:

```
pyinstaller --onefile <python3_Script>.py
```

Following are the packages I am using in my script:

- import PyPDF4
- import requests
- import PySimpleGUI as sg
- import re
- import pandas as pd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the [PyInstaller Manual](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) which states

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into
> a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing
> a Python interpreter or any modules.

You may also be interested in [What PyInstaller Does and How It Does It](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#:%7E:text=To%20your%20users%2C%20the%20app,have%20Python%20installed%20at%20all.&text=The%20output%20of%20PyInstaller%20is,the%20active%20version%20of%20Python.) where you can find your answer

> You distribute the bundle as a folder or file to other people, and
> they can execute your program. To your users, the app is
> self-contained. They do not need to install any particular version of
> Python or any modules. They do not need to have Python installed at
> all.

Also, keep in mind that

> The output of PyInstaller is specific to the active operating system
> and the active version of Python.

Comment: Thanks, @NicoCaldo. I verified on a Windows OS system and the executable file is working fine as that system did not have Python and utilities. Hope this will work on Mac OS as well.